# WebStorm's 'CoffeeScript Source Map' File Watcher generates an error

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

I am trying to get chrome to use source maps so I can walk through my coffeescript not the transpiled javascript.

Using WebStorm 7, I have added a `CoffeeScript Source Map` File Watcher, like so:

[image: webstorm settings - file watchers]

Now whenever I make a change to a coffeescript file I see the following error:

[image: source map error]

Can you tell me the correct way to generate source maps for my coffeescript files so I can step through the coffeescript rather than the transpiled javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please remove the second watcher (CoffeeScript Source map) and edit the first one as follows:

```
Program: C:\Users\janderson\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd
Arguments:  --compile --map $FileName$
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map
```