# WebStorm IDE File watch for coffeescript create an empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, webstorm

I am trying to automatically generate a js file from a coffeescript file with file watcher.

I followed this answer : [WebStorm's 'CoffeeScript Source Map' File Watcher generates an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769474/webstorms-coffeescript-source-map-file-watcher-generates-an-error#new-answer)

It does create the file but it is empty.

In the output console, it's giving me the the following line

> cmd.exe /D /C C:/Users/wmehanna/AppData/Roaming/npm/coffee.cmd --compile --map index.coffee

that when manually executed works.

I am using Webstorm 8.04 and Windows 8.1 as OS.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, if anyone encounter this problem, be sure to uncheck "Create output file from stdout".